# How to provision AWS Resources with Account Id only

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk

***I do have my AWS Account Id only***, and don't have any IAM user credentials. I want to provision some resources through CFN template. Is there any option to provision the resources by providing the ***AWS AccountId*** instead of user credential?

Comment: What do you mean by "AWS Account Id only"? With "AWS Account Id only" you can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need IAM credentials (Access Key + Secret Key) to use the account.

This is to be expected, since if I knew your Account Number, then you wouldn't want *me* doing things in your AWS Account.

The Account Number is not 'secret'.

Answer (score 0):

We need an IAM credential to provision any resources.

Alternatively, we can provision the resources with the ***role assume***. But here also we need to fetch the ***temporary credentials*** from the role, and that can be used to provision the resources.